# Unable to install Application Insights in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am unable to install Application Insights to my Azure Web App.

All I'm getting in Azure is the following error message.

> Could not install extension.

I don't have Azure Technical Support.

Is there something I need to do with my code to make it work, or is this a product issue with Application Insights in Azure?

Comment: Can you give more details on how you are tying to install the extension?

Comment: Could you please check ApplicationInsightsExtension.log in LogFiles in Kudu to see if actual installation succeeded or was interrupted? If it doesn't have any [Error] messages and ends with "End of Application Insights installation and configuration" then everything is fine and you can safely ignore the exception in UX as it seems to be some transient connectivity issue.

Comment: I got the error message when trying to install in Kudu. "Failure happened during instrumentation: Application Insights extension doesn't support ASP.NET Core 1.x applications. Please enable Application Insights through the application project code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I have created a test web app and installed the Application Insights extension. It works well.

I suggest you firstly created a new web app(or scale up and down the service plan) and install the Application Insights extension again.

Here are two way to install the extension.

1.Use web app portal.

[image]

2.Use KUDU tool

[image]

Open the extension and install the Application Insights

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kudu gave a more useful error message. "Failure happened during instrumentation: Application Insights extension doesn't support ASP.NET Core 1.x applications. Please enable Application Insights through the application project code."

Comment: i got this same message today using this guide to connect a .net core website to application insights via an ARM template: http://winterdom.com/2017/08/01/aiarm.html

Comment: I suggest you could start a new thread with details information for us to help you solve this issue.